# Flexbox challenge: how to get row wrapping with children identical and uniform margins in full rows

Tags: html, css, grid, flexbox

Ok, so I want to use flexbox to create a grid of perfectly uniform children that uses the screen size to determine the width of the children and how many to place on a row..

Things I want to be uniform:

1. The width of all children. The should be identical in all rows and
   determined by "full" rows.
2. All margins in "full" rows must be uniform both between children and on the outer left and right sides.
3. At least the height of all children in the same row (if some rows are taller than others it is ok, although the best implementation would indeed make all rows identical heights).
4. The text should be vertically centered in all children.

I want to have the items center in the final row if it is not filled, so on that row, it is fine (and indeed preferred) if the extreme margins outside of the children are larger on the left and the right.

I have three solutions that get close but nothing that hits the mark.

1. This version has everything I want except for the width of the children. If you notice the extreme left and right margins are larger than those between the children on the full rows. Ideally, I would like the children stretch enough so that their margins on full rows are identical both on the sides (outside of the group) and between the children, and then apply that same width to the overflowing children on the final row (who can have larger margins on the left and right).

```css
#container{
  list-style-type: none !important;
  display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content:center;
 /*style*/
 padding: 0.5em;
 background-color: royalblue;

}

.child {
  display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   /*style*/
   margin: 0.5em;
   padding: 1em;
 /*  min-height: 80px;*/
   width: 100px;
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul id ="container">
        <li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li>
</ul>
```

2. This version has the width/margin right, but the text is not vertically centered when one box has more text than the others in its row.

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

li {
  min-width: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-basis: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media (min-width: 200px) {
  li {
    max-width: 50%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 300px) {
  li {
    max-width: 33.33333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 400px) {
  li {
    max-width: 25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 500px) {
  li {
    max-width: 20%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
  li {
    max-width: 16.66667%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 700px) {
  li {
    max-width: 14.28571%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  li {
    max-width: 12.5%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 900px) {
  li {
    max-width: 11.11111%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  li {
    max-width: 10%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1100px) {
  li {
    max-width: 9.09091%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  li {
    max-width: 8.33333%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1300px) {
  li {
    max-width: 7.69231%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1400px) {
  li {
    max-width: 7.14286%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1500px) {
  li {
    max-width: 6.66667%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1600px) {
  li {
    max-width: 6.25%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1700px) {
  li {
    max-width: 5.88235%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1800px) {
  li {
    max-width: 5.55556%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1900px) {
  li {
    max-width: 5.26316%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 2000px) {
  li {
    max-width: 5%;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 2100px) {
  li {
    max-width: 4.7619%;
  }
}

ul, li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}

ul {
  background-color: tomato;
}

li .content {
  margin: 0.5em;
  background-color: darkgreen;
}
li img {
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
li figure, li img {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          I am taller then the other children on this row        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
      <li>
        <div class="content">
          hi there
        </div>
      </li>
</ul>
```

3. This version, gets the margins and heights right, but it doesn't keep the widths of children in the unfilled rows the same size as the widths in the children of the filled rows.  **This is actually very important.** I'd prefer the first version (with unequal side margins), over this.

```css
ul, li {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#container{
  list-style-type: none !important;
  display: flex;
 flex-flow: row wrap;
 justify-content:center;

 /*style*/
 padding: 0.5em;
 background-color: royalblue;

}

.child {
  display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   /*style*/
   margin: 0.5em;
   padding: 1em;
   min-height: 80px;
  min-width: 80px;  
  flex-grow: 1;
  /* width: 25%;*/
   background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<ul id ="container">
        <li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li><li class ="child"><a href="http://www.google.com"><span class="tf"></span><div class="tf2">Name 1<br>location</div></a></li>

</ul>
```

Comment: Basically....this isn't really possible with flexbox...that's not what it's for. You really need a grid framework...and that's not flexbox.

Comment: Sorry, then what are you saying, that I have to hard code everything?

Comment: You have to accept that flexbox is not a grid system...it's just another layout method. It solves some problems...but not all of them.

Comment: I can accept it - can you show me a solution?

Comment: That's my point....there isn't one.

Comment: Actually it seems your version 2 does already what you want. The `li` items stretches to the highest item in the row. If you give the `li` item a border you will see this. ( [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5pbgd1z/) ). It is just the divs inside with the green background which stay at their content size.

Comment: Hmmm.I'd also need to have the text vertically centered in the divs....

Comment: There are surly more techniques to do so, but you can make your li items `display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center` as well. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z5pbgd1z/1/)

Comment: @michaPau - this is the answer if you want credit, fill in the answer form. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help of @michaPau and by using sass I am able to get everything I asked for. I added this bit of code to my "version 2" as he/she suggested and it works.

```
/* this is the additional code that gets it to work: thanks to @michaPau */

li    
  display: flex
  justify-content: center 
  align-items: center

/*  --- end of michaPau's code --- */
```

Here is the codepen with the functional code.  You need to hit the compile button to convert from sass to pure css:
http://codepen.io/ihatecoding/pen/KzyjrE

This is the html:

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      I am taller then the other children on this row        </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="content">
      hi there
    </div>
  </li>
```

this is the complete sass (which includes @michaPau's fix):

```
<!-- language: lang-css -->


=flex-wrap-fix($flex-basis, $max-viewport-width)
  flex-grow: 1
  flex-basis: $flex-basis
  max-width: 100%

  $multiplier: 1
  $current-width: 0px

  @while $current-width < $max-viewport-width
    $current-width: $current-width + $flex-basis
    $multiplier: $multiplier + 1

    @media (min-width: $flex-basis * $multiplier)
      max-width: percentage(1 / $multiplier)

ul
  display: flex
  flex-wrap: wrap
  justify-content: center

li
  // I want the width to be between the following two sizes
  min-width: 40px
  text-align: center
  //max-width: 100px
  // this keeps all the elements the same size
  // **as long as they are on the same row**
  // but I want them to all the same width everywhere
  //flex: 1 0 0

  +flex-wrap-fix(100px, 2000px)

// demo styles

ul, li
  margin: 0
  padding: 0
  list-style: none

ul
  background-color: tomato

li  
  .content 
    margin: .5em
    background-color: darkgreen

/* this is the extra new code thanks to @michaPau */

li    
  display: flex
  justify-content: center 
  align-items: center

/*  ---end of michaPau's code --- */

  // the image may have variable width, I want it to take the entire space calculated by flexbox
  img
    width: 100%
    opacity: .5

  figure, img
    margin: 0
    padding: 0
```

Comment: One thing that was tripping me up forever in similar circumstances was flex-basis default has a huge impact when dealing with potential grid equality disruption. here's the visual depiction of [flex-basis 0 vs auto](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/images/rel-vs-abs-flex.svg) from w3

Comment: I don't understand in the why in the `flexbox: auto` example you provided, the two elements that have the same text ("short") differ in width. Can you explain that `@systemaddict`?

Comment: I'll restate: flex-basis sets the initial sizing of the inner flexbox item. As stated in the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) the default is  `auto`. **`flex-basis:auto`** deals with space (essentially) not used by content. It takes the content into sizing consideration. This isn't a problem with all the content is the same size - maybe a monotype character, or a picture/div of same size.          To computer size based 'top-down' purely on desired ratio of elements then you need to use **`flex-basis:0;`**

Comment: does that make sense now?